# Better D Documentation

Tags: d

Where can I find good solid D documentation? I've been trying to learn D, and am having issues finding good reference docs for the language.

For instance, I see op opImplicitCast talked about back in 2007...was that ever implemented?

Overall the language information seems to be extremely fragmented between dsource the digitalmars site and the public wiki. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Documentation on is located on [Digital Mars](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/lex.html) and [The D Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361). It isn't always accurate but that is the documentation. You will not find opImplicitCast because it was decided not to include because of the inclusion of 'alias this.' Aside from asking your best source for following development of D is on [Wiki4D](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?LanguageDevel).

Answer (score 12):

[Andrei Alexandrescu's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361), "The D programming Language", is currently considered the most authoritative specification.  Everything in it was discussed with Walter Bright, who writes the reference compiler.  Where the book and the implementation disagree, both Walter and Andrei agree that the implementation will be fixed in the near future to match the book.